# noClassDefFoundError in Android Project, but libraries added

Tags: android, eclipse, noclassdeffounderror, kryo

I try to use Kryo within my android project.

But I get a noClassDefFoundError Error during runtime. There is no syntaxerror highlithing during coding. The Error appears in the logcat at runtime.

[image]

I have added the nessecary libraries to my Android Project. The jar files are physically in my libs folder of my Android Project Folder.

[image]

[image]

After checking the libraries also in "Order and Export" I get a new NoDefClassFound error.

[image]

[image]

Any ideas ?

Comment: and in the "Order and Export" tab those libs are checked as well?

Comment: Thanks for the Hint. They were not checked. I guess I am a step further. But now I get the next ClassnotFound error. I added new screenshots to the question.

Comment: This usually happens when javac can find the class to compile sources but the dalvik can not find the library to load. Double check the presence of the libraries files inside you apk unziping it.